# while loop in R - the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r

I need to generate normal random variables with Marsaglia-Bray algorithm in R. The algorithm looks like this:

```
while(X>1)
   generate U1,U2~Unif[0,1]
   U1<-2*U1-1, U2<-2*U2-1
   X<-U1^2+U2^2
end
Y<-sqrt(-2*log(X)/X)
Z1<-U1*Y
Z2<-U2*Y
return Z1,Z2
```

In part of the code there is a mistake

```
x <- numeric(100)
while(x>1){
      u1 <- runif(1)
      u2 <- runif(1)
      u1 <- 2*u1-1
      u2 <- 2*u2-1
      x <- u1^2+u2^2
}
Warning message:
In while (x > 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Don't know how to solve it, can someone help please?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `while` in a loop:

`for(i in 1:100)
{
while(x>1){...}
}`

Comment: The result I need to get is vector x (x<-u1^2+u2^2) with 100 elements that are less or equal to 1 (that is why while (x>1) loop), but in this case `for(i in 1:100)
{
while(i>1){...}
}`
I get only one element
`x <- numeric(100)
for(x in 1:100){
while(x>1){
      u1 <- runif(1)
      u2 <- runif(1)
      u1 <- 2*u1-1
      u2 <- 2*u2-1
      x <- u1^2+u2^2
}
}` - this is my code

Comment: The `for` loop is a good idea, but you need to use `x[i]` inside the while loop. (Also I really dislike the statement "You must use while in a loop" - `while` **is itself a loop** and most of the time it doesn't need to be inside another loop.)

Comment: @ Gregor: You're right, that statement is not always true. Editing.